# Select count in parent table

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, ms-access-2016

I have two tables (table one is parent and table two is children) in ms access that are related together with ID

Table one :

[image: Table one]

table two :

[image: Table two]

and I need a select sql code to run this query:

[image]

I could write the sql command without count of TeamName :

```
Select Table1.TackName,Sum(Table2.PaintingValue) as SumofPaintingValue
from (Table1 INNER JOIN
      Table2
      on (Table1.ID = Table2.fgk)
GROUP BY Table1.TackName
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
Select TrackName,  Sum(PaintingValue) as SumOfPaintingValue, Dcount( "TrackName","Table1","TrackName='" & a.TrackName & "'") as CountOfTeamName   from Table1 as a INNER JOIN Table2  as b ON a.ID = b.fgk
group by TrackName
```

OR

Create two saved query

**qryA**

`Select TrackName, count(TrackName)  as CountOfTeamName from Table1 as a group by TrackName`

**qryB**

`Select TrackName,  Sum(PaintingValue) as SumOfPaintingValue  from Table1 as a INNER JOIN Table2  as b ON a.ID = b.fgk group by TrackName`

**Then use below for result**

`Select qryA.TrackName,  SumOfPaintingValue, CountOfTeamName  from qryA INNER JOIN qryB on qryA.TrackName = qryB.TrackName`

Comment: The result is wrong for count field because you count all the row in the query, the sql command must count distinct for TeamName, in another words TeamName should be counted from parent table and not children table, actually you count all the row in the children table, but I want to count of teams that worked on a track

Comment: @bahmanjafari Did you try the updated code?

Comment: Thank you so much for your helping, but I would use one select query to perform it not using several query.

Comment: @bahmanjafari So you can use the first one mentioned with Dcount

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't seen your first method.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this at the moment, but I think a correlated query should do the trick:

```
Select 
Table1.TackName,
Sum(Table2.PaintingValue) as SumofPaintingValue,
(select count(TeamName) from table1 t1 where t1.TrackName=table1.TrackName
group by TeamName) as CountOfTeams
from Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 on (Table1.ID = Table2.fgk) 
GROUP BY Table1.TackName
```

Comment: As i know Access doesn't support "count(distinct TeamName)"

Comment: @bahmanjafari , I changed it to use group by instead of distinct